# Show image next to the comment author if have certain role

Tags: comments, user-roles, conditional-content

I want to create a badge image for comment author of a certain role, say, Editor. I want to style comments of users with the Editor role differently than comments of non-registered or lower-level users. For instance, I'd like to have an image appear next to his/her name.

I can do the whole thing in CSS, but I want a bit more flexibility so I can add more juice. How can I do it with a conditional tag? Any ideas?

Comment: @ Milo Did you ever got it to work ? I really need that option as well I hope you will share the final result with me. Franco

Answer (score 1):

[Conditional tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) are used to change content on the basis of what conditions a page meets. While there are no conditional tags depending on a user's role, this is how you can manipulate content depending on roles:

**Display content to the user, depending on his role**

```
<?php
   global $current_user;
   get_currentuserinfo(); //not strictly required, $current_user should be populated anyway 
   if(in_array('editor', $current_user->roles)) {
      // echo markup here
   }
?>
```

Alternatively, you might also want to check out [`current_user_can()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can)

**Edit: Display content based on a commentator's role**

```
<?php
   $commentator_id = get_comment(get_comment_ID())->user_id;
   $commentator_info = get_userdata($commentator_id);
   $capabilities = $user_info->wp_capabilities;
   if (array_key_exists('editor', $capabilities)) {
      // echo markup here
   }
?>
```

The above will have to go in the comments loop.

Resources:
[get_comment()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comment) | [get_user_data()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_userdata) | [Comment Loop Beauty](http://codex.wordpress.org/User%3aJalenack/Comment_Loop_Beauty)

Comment: Thanks for the snippet! The above code only examine whether the login user is editor and then show something to him. But what I want to do is to display certain badge for the comment author. Say if the comment author is an Editor, an Editor badge will show next to his comment, and everybody else can see the badge. It's kind like assign badge to certain users without using CSS. Any idea about how I can do it?

Comment: @Milo I have updated the answer. See Edits.

Comment: Thanks Johannes! I tried out the code but it didn't work. Nothing showed up. I tried several roles but still nothing showed up. I also tried the "Comment Loop Beauty" one, by using `$comment->user_id == '1'`, it works well but only a certain user ID is allowed.

Comment: @Milo where and how did you use the 2nd snippet? What file(s) of your theme are you editing? Can you show some of your relevant code?

Comment: I use a custom function for the comment template. Inside `comments.php`: `<?php
       $commentator_id = get_comment(get_comment_ID())->user_id;
       $commentator_info = get_userdata($commentator_id);
       $capabilities = $user_info->wp_capabilities;
       if (array_key_exists('editor', $capabilities)) {
          echo 'Editor' ;
       }
    ?>` The complete code is here: https://gist.github.com/1355876

Answer (score 0):

Ok; so I found a 4 year old function that's never been committed to core:

http://core.trac.wordpress.org/attachment/ticket/5290/author-template-the_author_role.diff

... so my guess is that by using this; we can do a simple if statement in the loop to show something if the post author is in a role/capability; but not sure how that relates to comment authors.